# Kivy Line(circle=(x, y, r)) - radius Animation

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

My expectation:

Circle with radius 100px will be animated to radius 150px. Solution probably will be simple, but this problem is out of my knoweledge...

#### Minimal Example

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Line, Ellipse
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.animation import Animation


class AnimationExample(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.animate, 2)

        with self.canvas:
            self.pulsating_line = Line(
                        circle=(self.center_x, self.center_y, 100),
                        width=2)

        self.bind(size = self.update,
                    pos = self.update
                    )

    def update(self, *args):
        self.pulsating_line.circle = (self.center_x,
                                      self.center_y,
                                      100,
                                      )
    def animate(self, *args):
        print('Animate')

        circ = self.pulsating_line
        circ.circle = (self.center_x,
                       self.center_y,
                       100,
                       )
        circ.width = 2

        # This works for animated "width"
        Animation(width=8,
            t='out_bounce',
            d=1.1).start(circ)
   
        # In my opinion is this analogical approach, but of course, it not works :/
        # Animation(circle=(self.center_x,
        #                   self.center_y,
        #                   150,
        #                   ),
        #           t='out_bounce',
        #           d=0.8).start(circ)

class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AnimationExample()

TutorialApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A convenient way to animate canvas instructions is by using `Properties` and `kv`. The `kv` automatically sets up bindings the the `Properties`, so the animation is simply animating those `Properties`. Here is a modified version of your code that uses that approach:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.animation import Animation

kv = '''
<AnimationExample>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.circle_color
        Line:
            circle: self.center_x, self.center_y, self.radius  # this sets up bindings to the Properties defined in AnimationExample
            width: self.line_width  # this sets up a binding to the line_width Property
        
'''


class AnimationExample(BoxLayout):
    # define properties for the circle
    circle_color = ListProperty([1, 0, 0, 1])
    radius = NumericProperty(100)
    line_width = NumericProperty(2)

    def animate(self, *args):
        # since the kv sets up bindings to the properties of this class, we can just animate those properties
        print('Animate')

        # This works for animated "width"
        width_anim = Animation(line_width=8, t='out_bounce', d=1) + Animation(line_width=2, t='out_bounce', d=1)
        width_anim.start(self)

        # to animate the circle radius
        radius_anim = Animation(radius=150, d=1) + Animation(radius=100, d=1)
        radius_anim.start(self)


class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        r = AnimationExample()
        Clock.schedule_interval(r.animate, 2)
        return r


TutorialApp().run()
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt answer. And i have one additional question: When i have more circles with different radiuses, do i need to use specific ID (in *.kv) for each circle? Thanks.

Comment: You can't assign `ids` to canvas instructions. But you can can just have several `Properties` for the different radii, or you can have a list of radii in a `ListProperty`.